# Обратная пагинация в CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Как сделать обратную пагинацию в CakePHP 2.x
Например:

> 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1
>   Или с 1й страницы, но чтобы записи начинались с последней

Comment: А вам точно такое надо, а не, к примеру, вытянуть с базы данный в обратном порядке?

Comment: пробовал array_reverse но данные сортируются именно на странице, а где в контроллере они всем скопом из базы берутся найти не могу

Comment: ну поищите название таблицы через поиск)) это же не проблема.  судя по [ресурсу](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) там уже можно будет задать фильтр сортировки а-ля `$this->Article->find('first', array(
        'order' => array('Article.created' => 'desc')
    ));`

Comment: в контроллере `$this->set('tests', $this->paginate());` уже в функции `paginate()` идёт вся выборка как понял но если там изменить порядок, то и в других случаях изменится

Comment: Вам надо побольше почитать [документацию](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html). Можно непосредственно в контроллере как для него всего, так и для конкретного экшна задать параметры пагинации: сортировку, лимит, поля и прочее.